# How to check if the date is today or not

Tags: android, date, date-comparison

I am getting the current date like below:

```
public void getCurrentDate(View view) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy / MM / dd ");
    String strDate = "Current Date : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
    display(strDate);
}
private void display(String num) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_date_view);
    textView.setText(num);
}
```

But I want to check whether the date is today's date or not. But I am not getting how to check that.

Comment: Unfortunately, Android will give you the system date which can be easily changed from settings. To have actual date you need to verify using internet

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 5):

You can do as @aliaksei's answer, which works fine. But in Android you can also use [java.time](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) (API level 26) or [ThreetenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) if java.time is not available.

But first you must consider the fact that "today's date" is relative. Now, at this very moment, each part of the world might be in a different "today". In America and Europe it's April 10th, but in some parts of the Pacific it's already April 11th.

You can choose a specific timezone, or just use the device's zone, which I think it's the case. In this case, just use the JVM default timezone.

Then you use the ThreetenABP to convert the `Calendar` to a `LocalDate` and then compare with today's date:

```
// calendar I want to check
Calendar cal = ...

// convert to LocalDate
LocalDate date = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(cal).toLocalDate();

// compare with today (now() is using the JVM default timezone)
if (date.isEqual(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))) {
    // today
}
```

Comment: @OleV.V.  To me it's still confusing that there are 2 methods: equals and isEqual. Reading the docs I saw that there's really a subtle difference between them. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The difference becomes clearer when you compare for example `ZonedDateTime` objects. `isEqual` will tell you whether they denote the same point in time, while `equals` will check whether they are exactly equal (same zone and more). Most of all I dislike the type unsafety of `equals`: it accepts any `Object` without objection, potentially leaving you with very strange results.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
    if (cal1 == null || cal2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dates must not be null");
    }
    return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA) &&
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
            cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
}
```

Or you could use the [DateUtils](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/Checksifacalendardateistoday.htm) class that this snippet is from :)

Comment: what will be the two param here while calling the method.
isSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2)  @aliaksei

Comment: Why overcomplicate things when you can just use .DATE?

Comment: @FlyingNades That will compare the day of the month only, so September 10, 1968 would be considered equal to April 10, 2018, for example.